# Scraping user reviews from imdb in python

Tags: python, screen-scraping, imdb

I am deeply in need of an api or a piece of code that can extract the "user reviews" of a certain movie from imdb page. 
can someone help me please?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out above, Scraping would not be a good idea. But IMDBPy package provides a [Movie class](http://imdbpy.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/imdbpy/imdbpy/file/e635eac749aa/imdb/Movie.py), which has amazon reviews. This is different from User Reviews tough.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid IMDB doesnt allow that:

> **Robots and Screen Scraping**: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below.

http://www.imdb.com/help/show_article?conditions